# Can't assign to operator?

Tags: livewires, python

Several questions have the same error, but I'm just starting Python and don't understand it.
I'm trying to create a program which generates two random numbers, nicknames these numbers, asks the user what the answer is, multiplies the two numbers and gives a nickname to THAT number, then it reads the user's answer and sees if the user's answer is the same as the one it got. I started with a simpler program that asks the same question three times.

My program is the following:

```
def math ():
    for f in range (3):
        x=10
        c=5
        x*c=p
        print x,'times',c,'.'
        v=read_number('What is the answer?')
        if p==v:
            print 'You got it right!'
        else:
            print 'You got it wrong.'
```

And now that I look at it line 6 it is unnecessary. But when I finish it Python says 'SyntaxError: can't assign to operator.'
It also highlights after c=5. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The

```
x*c=p
```

should read

```
p=x*c
```

This multiplies `x` by `c` and assigns the result to `p`.

Comment: Thanks! Teacher is too busy helping students 2 lessons behind.

Answer (score 0):

you use randint() from the random module to generate random numbers,  for example:

```
from random import randint

x = randint(0,10)   # random between 0 and 10
c = randint(0,10)

p = x * c

print p
```

Comment: Um, this doesn't answer my question but it helps.